# How to generate csr file by X.509 certificate

Tags: java, cryptography

I wanna know how to generate csr file by using X.509 certificate standard.
What the different between X500Name and X509Name? I wanna add subject data with :
**Common Name, Organization, Organization Unit, Locality, Country, State and Email.**
Please explain how to generate csr file and give me some link.

Where do i add email in this X500Name?

X500Name x500Name = new X500Name(CN, OU, O, L, S, C);

Please explain me!!!

Thanks.

Comment: You want to generate it using code or just the keytool?

Comment: See [this page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation) for the instructions on how to use excellent BouncyCastle library

Answer (score 0):

X.500 is more general standard about organization of objects. X500Name is a name of such object in some structural repository/system.
X.509 is a substandard related to security objects, certificates, algorithms. [See more >>](http://www.x500standard.com/)

> What the different between X500Name and X509Name?

X509Name could (incorrectly) be a name of certificate property - it should reather be e.g. "X500Name of some X509 cetificate attribute"